# HttpClient.PostAsync causes 400 error when passing JSON to API

Tags: json, api, asp.net-core, bugzilla

I am trying to pass some data in JSON format to the Bugzilla API but am getting a `400` response. I am using `Netwonsoft.Json` to generate the JSON and it from what I can tell it is generated fine so I am not really sure what is causing the 400 error.

Code:

```
var Client = new HttpClient();

Dictionary <string, string> BugData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Bugzilla_api_key", "Removed for scurity" },
    { "product", "Test" },
    { "component", "Test Component" },
    { "version", "unspecified" },
    { "summary", "Basic API Test" },
    { "description", "A basic API test" }
};

string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BugData, Formatting.Indented);

var Response = await Client.PostAsync("http://bugzillaaddress/rest/bug", new StringContent(Json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

The JSON it appears to be generating is:

```
{
    "Bugzilla_api_key": "Removed for security",
    "product": "Test",
    "component": "Test Component",
    "version": "unspecified",
    "summary": "Basic API Test",
    "description": "A basic API test"
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Full Error response:

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Connection: close
  Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 13:36:01 GMT
  ETag: IzeHlNLRTewC8+btLeGxXA
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  Access-control-allow-headers: origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with
  Access-control-allow-origin: *
  X-content-type-options: nosniff
  X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
  X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
  Content-Length: 11
  Content-Type: text/html
}}
```

This is what Fiddler sees:

> POST http://bugzilla-tools/rest/bug HTTP/1.1 Content-Type:
>   application/json; charset=utf-8 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length:
>   193 Host: bugzilla-tools
>
> {"Bugzilla_api_key":"Removed for
>   security","product":"Test","component":"Test
>   Component","version":"unspecified","summary":"Basic API
>   Test","description":"A basic API test"}

Edit: Response from Bugzilla Team

I am apparently not passing an Accept header in with my request which they require. If I add an accept header I should be good. Anyone know how to do that? (I am looking right now and playing with things but if someone has code I can copy and past to end 4 days of fighting with this API that would be great!)

Comment: 1) Remove the indenting, it is only taking up extra data space.  2) Can you show us the exact error message, maybe using something like Fiddler will help.

Comment: @ShaunSharples I have edited the post to include the full response I get when running the `PostAsync` command.

Comment: I think I am out of ideas. In theory, what you have looks correct, even after confirming with the BugZilla API documentation and your JSON in the question is properly formatted. I would suggest maybe try using `RestSharp RestClient` to rule out any weird behaviour from the HttpClient. Also you could test using Fiddler, and putting your JSON manually in the Request body.

Comment: @ShaunSharples Unfortunately RestSharp does not support the new ASP.Net 5 Core. I will look into this Fillder thing

Comment: @ShaunSharples I updated the post with what I found in fiddler.

Comment: @ShaunSharples Apparently I need to add an Accept header, ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Sure thing, instead of `Client.PostAsync` use `Client.SendAsync`. This requires you creating a new `HttpRequestMessage` which has a Headers property. The header you need is `Accept: application/json`. I am on phone so can't easily write some sample code sorry.

Comment: @ShaunSharples I am new to the HttpClient so if you get a moment to throw some code up, and it works, I will give you the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi Matt, if my answer helped you solve your problem please mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: @ShaunSharples I am actually still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get onto my PC.  Here is some sample code.

```
var Client = new HttpClient();

Dictionary <string, string> BugData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Bugzilla_api_key", "Removed for scurity" },
    { "product", "Test" },
    { "component", "Test Component" },
    { "version", "unspecified" },
    { "summary", "Basic API Test" },
    { "description", "A basic API test" }
};

string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BugData, Formatting.Indented);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://bugzillaaddress/rest/bug");

request.Content = new StringContent(Json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

var Response = await Client.SendAsync(request);
```

**Edit**

I actually noticed that you can do this using `PostAsync` as well.

Change it to this.

```
var Client = new HttpClient();

Dictionary <string, string> BugData = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Bugzilla_api_key", "Removed for scurity" },
    { "product", "Test" },
    { "component", "Test Component" },
    { "version", "unspecified" },
    { "summary", "Basic API Test" },
    { "description", "A basic API test" }
};

string Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BugData, Formatting.Indented);

var content = new StringContent(Json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
content.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");

var Response = await Client.PostAsync("http://bugzillaaddress/rest/bug", content);
```

Comment: I am not sure if you edit actually works as when I step though my task it kicks back up to the calling action as soon as it processes the `content.headers.add` line and never gets to the `PostAsync` line

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it showed how to pass the Accept header which allowed me to move onto the next error. As a note I thought it was not fixed initially since IIS was not returning the json error info to IE but after using a program called Postman I was able to get the json error information.